# Android Wear: Passing variable from data object into watch face service

Tags: android, wear-os

I have data coming across from the handheld app that I call up on data change:

```
    @Override
    public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Data changed: " + dataEvents);
        for (DataEvent event : dataEvents) {
            if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_DELETED) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DataItem deleted: " + event.getDataItem().getUri());
            } else if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DataItem changed: " + event.getDataItem().getUri());
                if (event.getDataItem().getUri().getPath().endsWith(Data.PATH_SPEED)) {
                    DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(event.getDataItem());
                    // This is where I get the data for speedReport from the DataMap
                    String speedReport = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getString(Data.SPEED_REPORT);
                }
            }
        } 
    };
```

I am trying to get speedReport to carry over to onDraw, in this sort of format:

```
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, Rect bounds) {
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, bounds.width(), bounds.height(), mBackgroundPaint);
        float x = mXOffset;

        // This is where I want to pass the variable for speedReport from the DataMap
        if (speedReport != null) {
            canvas.drawText(speedReport, x - 80, (mYOffset + 14), mAmPmPaint);
        } else {
            canvas.drawText("Loading Data", x - 80, (mYOffset + 14), mAmPmPaint);
        }
    }
```

When I was doing this with an activity (i.e. for a regular wear app, not a watch face), I just used setText and applied it to the corresponding textview.  But this is proving to be more complicated than that.  It isn't accepting the variable outright.  I need to pass it in with some sort of mechanism.  Maybe a handler or something else?

What is the best way to carry the data from the DataMap to onDraw?  Could you provide an example as a guide?

**Update:**
As I mention below, I tried setting speedReport to null, but basically speedReport comes up null every time doing that, even when there is data getting into the DataMap object.

I noticed that if I set the same speedReport variable that I set to "null" to "33" though, it pulls "33" through to onDraw. So defining a local variable works, it just isn't taking that value from the data object.

I added a log: 
Log.d(TAG, "DataItem String: " + speedReport);

after the line for: String speedReport = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getString(Data.SPEED_REPORT);

The log reports back whatever variable I expected from the handheld, indicating that the data is getting across to the wearable app and is stored within the data object. But the data isn't getting out of onDataChanged.

In the spirit of helping others that are hitting this issue, I do have a temporary solution I can share. I saved the data to shared preferences and then pulled back out of shared preferences in onDraw.  This works technically, but my question still stands, what is the best way to carry the data from the DataMap to onDraw?  Could you provide an example as a guide?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using `CanvasWatchFace`, so what you should do, is this:

1. create `speedReport` field and set it to `null`
2. when you receive `onDataChanged` callback with a new `DataMap`, set `speedReport` and call `invalidate()`
3. in `onDraw' check if`speedReport`is`null`; if yes, use`"Loading Data" string, otherwise use `speedReport value`.

Before the `TextView` would have a field that would hold the value of `speedReport` or the default text for you. Now you need to create your own field to keep it.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I tried this, but speedReport comes up null every time, even when there is data getting into the DataMap object.  Basically, if I set the same speedReport variable that I set to "null" to "33", it pulls "33" through to onDraw.

And I have a log:
Log.d(TAG, "DataItem String: " + speedReport); 

after the line for:
String speedReport = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getString(Data.SPEED_REPORT);  

The log reports back whatever variable I expected from the handheld, indicating that the data is getting across to the wearable app. But the data isn't getting out of onDataChanged.

Comment: I tried it with and without invalidate() where I define the data, and it doesn't seem to matter.  In this particular app, I have a handler that updates the UI every half second though, so I think that is pretty much offsetting this.  I do think invalidate() is helping to refresh the data when it does come in though, so it is useful to use. Just depends on how frequent you are using it in other places.